# next js - Why does it show a message not found when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I click on the link, my blog pages are displayed, but after reloading the page, the page is not found.

**path:**

-blog / [id].js

**[id].js**

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
        this.state={
         data:[],
        loading:true
        }
    }
      async componentDidMount(){
        console.log(Router.router)
        this.setState({
          loading : true
        })
        const id =  Router.router.query.id;

        this.setState({
          id
        })
        const res = await Api.get(`post.php?id=${id}`);
        this.setState({data:res.data.data});
}
 render() {
    return (
      <>
        ....
     </>
)
}

  export default Post;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, either in the console or in the Network tab?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error. Make sure you're not running the app multiple times. I resolved it by closing all ports. Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34705861)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `componentDidMount` will not be called server-side, the server returns nothing

`UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` (deprecated) is the only method running on the server lifecycle - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount